# $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f(x-r_n)$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying for an exam and I've encountered this exercise:

Let $f(x)=x^{-0.5}\mathbb{1}_{\{0<x<1\}}$ and ${\{r_n\}}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ some enumeration of the rationals. Let:

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f(x-r_n)$$

Prove that $F$ is integrable.

I would really appreciate a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Something like that? (We can replace the order due to Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem)
$\int F(x)=\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f(x-r_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int 2^{-n}f(x-r_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\int f(x-r_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}M<\infty$