# Difficulty showing that $\sum_n\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{x-r_n}}\chi_{(0,1)}(x-r_n)$ converges almost surely, where $(r_n)_n$ enumerates $\Bbb Q$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f \ (x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\chi_{(0,1)}(x)$ and let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of the rationals, prove that the series:

$$G(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{} \frac{f (x - r_n)}{2^n}$$Almost always converge and $G(x)$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Can the monotone convergence theorem be applied to the integral of $G$ to interchange sum and integral? How to compute the resulting trivial integral?

Comment: Change the title please. It should reflect the problem at hand

Comment: I saw you changed your title. However, it did not concisely express the problem (one must deal with the character limit!). So, I've edited it again

Comment: Seems like it was answered here using Fatou's lemma https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3162071/1104384

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $F(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} f(x - r_n)$ is integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162063/show-that-fx-sum-limits-n-1-infty-2-n-fx-r-n-is-integrable)

Comment: I do not understand, because in this year $ 2^n$ is found as a denominator.

Comment: $2^{-n} = \frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: So the procedure and answer for this exercise are exactly the same? sorry for the questions, i'm confused

Comment: Please, how is it shown if the monotone convergence theorem is applied to the integral of G to exchange sum and integral? Once that's done how to compute a trivial integral, ?